# frame-based counters or timers?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this frame-based counter I use instead of the timer-class because everything in my game is frame-based. This counter ensures that everything runs fine even when used on old computers.

I would like to know if it makes sense to create a tenth-second-frame-based-counter (or even a twentieth-second-frame-based counter). Basically it would be nearly the same counter like the one below except for the fact that the framesPerSecond-variable is divided by 10 or 20 and instead of using seconds I use tenthsesonds or twentiethseconds.

Is that a good or bad idea? Is there basically a difference between frame-based counters and timers when used on old computers?
I'm not sure about this topic therefore I ask.

```
{
import flash.events.*;


public class BasicFrameTimer extends EventDispatcher
{
    public static const TIME_IS_UP:String = "timesup";
    public var countUp:Boolean = false;
    public var min:int = 0;
    public var max:int;
    public var maxSet:Boolean = false;
    public var seconds:int;
    private var frameCount:int;
    public var started:Boolean = false;
    private var framesPerSecond:int;

    public function BasicFrameTimer(framesPerSecond:int) {
        this.framesPerSecond = framesPerSecond;

    }

    public function start():void {
        frameCount = 0;
        started = true;
    }

    public function stop():void {
        started = false;
    }

    public function reset():void {
        if (countUp) {
            seconds = 0;
        } else {
            seconds = max;
        }
    }

    public function update():void {

        if (started) {
            frameCount++;
            if (frameCount > (framesPerSecond)) {
                frameCount = 0;

                if (countUp) {
                    seconds++;

                    if (maxSet == true && seconds == max) {
                        stop();
                        dispatchEvent(new Event(TIME_IS_UP));
                    }
                } else {
                    seconds--;
                    if (seconds == min) {
                        stop();
                        dispatchEvent(new Event(TIME_IS_UP));
                    }
                }
            }

        }


    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between a [`Timer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) and using a [`frame event`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#event%3aenterFrame) with implications for how the stage is updated, not just on old computers.

You can set the suggested frames-per-second settings as part of the `.fla` file, and the compiled `.swf` will do its best to keep up with the suggested setting. If it can't, it starts skipping frames to keep up.

If you've defined some interactions, such as an animation, to happen on frame events, or via a frame counter, they will execute with the frames, meaning that a higher fps will cause a faster animation. If, instead, the animation relies on a timer, they will execute along with the timer.

Executing with a timer will preserve real-time interactions at the cost of some choppiness for animations. A good way to test that you've correctly implemented a timer for an update cycle is to bump the fps down to `1` or `2` and see if the animation completes within the same amount of time (±1s).

As you've tagged [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development), I'd recommend using a combination.

A cycle using `Timer` should be used to check input, load resources and check game state (`input`, `load`, `update`)

A cycle using `ENTER_FRAME` should be used to modify drawable assets (`render`)

A cycle using `EXIT_FRAME` should be used to unload resources (`unload`);

The reason for the combination is that you'll be able to perform the simple calculations on a regular time interval, but you wont waste time with any rendering-specific logic until rendering is actually necessary. Additionally, it will allow your time-critical assets to stay in sync even on slow machines.

Comment: However it seems that most flash developers don't separate their game logic with graphics..

Comment: @gladoscc, I would hazard a guess that most flash developers don't have any formal game development education. Which is not to say that their games are worse by any means, just that they haven't necessarily learned some of the design patterns common to game development.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer.:) Now I know I have absolutely no knowledge about this topic. I will have to do my "homework" and check all my timers. This thing seems to be more complicated than I thought initially.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve frame-rate independant animation is to use the `getTimer()` function. It returns the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the Flash VM started.

You should only perform your screen updates once per frame.

With `getTimer()` you can determine the precise number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the last frame (the last screen update). Using this value, you can easily make the necessary adjustments to the display list.

For instance, using this technique, a `Sprite` moving at 1 pixel per 50ms could *effectively* move at the same speed on all systems, even if the system is only capable of updating the screen once every 500ms.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You say getTimer() returns ms elapsed since flash VM started, then you say it tells you the ms passed since the last frame. Which one?

Comment: @gladoscc, subtraction gives you the difference between frames.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm totally unaware about this topic so I think I should check all my timers now and read some theoretic stuff about that.:)